# Google Cloud Storage upload using autoscalling under load balancer

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing, autoscaling

I have a problem when I upload images to Google Cloud Storage from Compute Engine instance group.

Previously I used machine A where the engine is running normally.
When a machine B starts up in the same group instance by using machine A's image, the upload does not work, 403 unathorized.

Even though there is a script for exporting credentials in the form of json as follows:

```
- gcloud auth activate-service-account xxxxxxt@xxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
--key-file = / home / username / key.json --project = xxxx-xxxx
- export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "/ home / username / key.json"
```

I use Python as a programming language.

When template B doesn't work, I return it again using template A and it works.

My update steps are as follows:

> update config on machine A -> create image from machine A with machine
>   name B -> create template from Image machine B -> use in the same
>   group instance -> replace machine A template with engine B template

Comment: Is your machine are on GCP?

Comment: Yes, my machine on gcp.

Comment: can you try to remove the `key.json` file and to set the service account into the Compute Engine configuration? On GCP, you don't need service account keys!

Comment: hello @guillaumeblaquiere thank you for the answer, I can give direct access to the machine with the identity and api access when making the machine, and for now the machine runs like normal again. thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I'm posting an answer on behalf of @guillaumeblaquiere who is the original solver of this issue:

In Compute Engine You don't need to pass credentials as json keys. Instead you should use the Compute Engine Service account and provide it with the right [IAM permisions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) to write to your Bucket